# How to set tabindex on library react components?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a React component that contains some third-party `<Button/>` elements, and I want to rearrange the tab-ordering, but it doesn't look like the component accepts a tabIndex prop. I have something like this:

```
import {Button} from 'thirdpartylibrary';
import TextPanel from './TextPanel.js';
const Component = ()=>{
    ...
    return (<>
                <TextPanel tabIndex={1}/>
                <div className="buttons-wrapper">
                    <Button tabIndex={2}>Btn1</Button>
                    <Button tabIndex={3}>Btn2</Button>
                </div>
            </>);

}
```

Basically, I want `<TextPanel/>` to get focus first and then the `<Button/>`, but the focus always starts from the `<Button/>` first. The browser inspector shows that the rendered HTML buttons don't pick up the tabindexes I assigned their "corresponding" react components. For what it's worth, I checked the `<Button/>` component's source code and it looks like it eventually inherits from a `ElementAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>` - does this mean that there's some way of assigning normal html props to it?